# How to calculate the indefinite integral of $f(x)=\frac{1}{A+B \cos 2x +C \cos x}$.

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I have tried substituting $x = \tan t$ but not able to get an integrable expression.

Comment: It's also possible to use $\tan(x/2) = t$.

Comment: @MrYouMath I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First use

$$\cos(x)=\dfrac{\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix)}{2}$$
$$\cos(2x)=\dfrac{\exp(2ix)+\exp(-2ix)}{2}$$

then substitute

$$\exp(ix)=u \implies i\exp(ix)dx = du \implies dx = \dfrac{du}{iu}.$$

The resulting integral can be solved by partial fractions.

---

A [standard alternative approach](http://www.nabla.hr/Z_MemoHU-133.htm) is to use (advantage is that you avoid complex numbers; disadvantage is that you have to remember this substitution :D)

$$t = \tan \dfrac{x}{2}$$
and substitute $\cos x = \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $dx = \dfrac{2dt}{1+t^2}$.